# Need a more efficient Python Loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am currently creating HTML code for 4 tables from 4 different tuples then printing out the entire HTML. I am doing this by looping through the tables in 4 separate loops. I have to use 4 separate loops because the table labels and column references are different. I'm looking for some suggestions on improving the efficiency of this (maybe combining down to one loop). In the below example, each tuple only has 1 row since it's just a sample, but when I actually code this, there will be many rows.

My code:

```
datatable1 = [('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F','G')]
datatable2 = [('H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M','N')]
datatable3 = [('O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T','U')]
datatable4 = [('W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z')]

HTML_Body1 = "Table1<BR><table>"    
for row in datatable1:
    HTML_Body1 = HTML_Body1 + "<tr><td><font size='2'><td>" + row[0] + "</td><td>" + row[1] + "</td><td><font size='2'>" + row[6] + "</td><td>" + row[4] + "</td></tr>"
HTML_Body1 = HTML_Body1 + "</table><BR><BR>"

HTML_Body2 = "Table2<BR><table>"
for row in datatable2:
    HTML_Body2 = HTML_Body2 + "<tr><td><font size='2'><td>" + row[0] + "</td><td>" + row[1] + "</td><td><font size='2'>" + row[6] + "</td><td>" + row[4] + "</td></tr>"
HTML_Body2 = HTML_Body2 + "</table><BR><BR>"

HTML_Body3 = "Table3<BR><table>"
for row in datatable3:
    HTML_Body3 = HTML_Body3 + "<tr><td><font size='2'><td>" + row[1] + "</td><td>" + row[2] + "</td><td><font size='2'>" + row[3] + "</td><td>" + row[0] + "</td></tr>"
HTML_Body3 = HTML_Body3 + "</table><BR><BR>"

HTML_Body4 = "Table4<BR><table>"    
for row in datatable4:
    HTML_Body4 = HTML_Body4 + "<tr><td><font size='2'><td>" + row[1] + "</td><td>" + row[2] + "</td><td><font size='2'>" + row[3] + "</td><td>" + row[0] + "</td></tr>"
HTML_Body4 = HTML_Body4 + "</table><BR><BR>"

Entire_HTML = "<HMTL>" + HTML_Body1 + HTML_Body2 + HTML_Body3 + HTML_Body4 + "</HTML>"

print Entire_HTML
```

Comment: Is there any rule for how you select which values of ```row``` get into the table?

Comment: When you say "efficiency," are you looking for fast code or readable code?

Comment: Among other issues this code won't work when you add more than one row per list since each loop preserves only the very last row you process in that loop.  Probably you want to move the first and last line of each loop body outside the loop.

Comment: @wnnmaw Not really no. They will come from various SQL queries where tables have different columns that don't always line up with each other.

Comment: @LarryLustig - You're right, sometimes oversimplifying things leads to errors. Corrected in the OP.

Comment: @Kevin I am only looping through about 500 rows of tuple. I assume there is not speed issues with this little data. I guess I'm more looking for readable code.

Comment: ...readable code, AND abiding to the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: i would suggest using a templating engine like Jina2 or Mako to make things a littel easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make each datatable object a little more complex you can process them more easily.

```
 datatables = [
     { 'header' : 'Table1', 'rows' : [('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F','G')], 'want_cols' : (0,1,6,4) },
     { 'header' : 'Table2', 'rows' : [('H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M','N')], 'want_cols' : (0,1,6,4) },
     { 'header' : 'Table3', 'rows' : [('O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T','U')], 'want_cols' : (1,2,3,0) },
     { 'header' : 'Table4', 'rows' : [('W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z')], 'want_cols' : (1,2,3,0) },
 ]

 output_html = ''
 for tbl in datatables:
      table_html = '{}<br/><table>'.format(tbl['header'])
      for row in tbl['rows']:
          table_html += '\n'.join(
               ['<tr><td>{}</tr></td>'.format(row[index]) for index in tbl['want_cols']]
          )
      table_html += '\n</table>'

      output_html += table_html
```

Further improvements are possible:

- Replace `for row in tbl['rows']:` with a nested list comprehension.
- Instead of dictionaries, use a DataTable class with header and rows properties.
- If the purpose of the data tables is primarily presentational you could include an asHtmlTable() method in the class definition, making assembling the tables into a larger piece of HTML almost declarative in style.

Comment: This yields a syntax error on the following line: `table_html = '{}<br/><table>'.format tbl['header']`. Also, this seems like it would include all columns for each table, not the specific detailed in OP.

Comment: I put the parens back on the format() call.  However, you're right that the OP is not asking for all columns in order, I'll patch that up in a minute.

Comment: I've added an extra property to each dictionary to control which columns are output in which order.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words.  The takeaway is keep it DRY.  There should be only one code implementation of doing the-same-or-similar-thing (producing an HTML table from a list of tuples) with the variance in that process encoded as data, not code.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, you could refactor the head, rows and tail of the table

```
def table_open(title):
    return title + "<BR><table>"

def table_row(d1, d2, d3, d4):
    return "<tr><font size='2'><td>" + d1 + "</td><td>" + d2 + "</td><td><font size='2'>" + d3 + "</td><td>" + d4 + "</td></tr>"

def table_close():
    return "</table><BR><BR>"
```

and use this instead

```
tr = ''
for row in datatable1:
    tr = tr + table_row(row[0], row[1], row[6], row[4])

HTML_Body1 = table_open("Table1") + tr + table_close()
```

---

A more compact form would be

```
tr = [table_row(row[0], row[1], row[6], row[4]) for row in datatable1]
HTML_Body1 = table_open("Table1") + ''.join(tr) + table_close()
```

which captures the rows first and concatenates them afterwards.